# The "Italian sounding" issue

Tags: word-usage

The expression "Italian sounding" is a recent expression used with the following meaning:

> - According to Confagricoltura, “Made in Italy” is now recording a turnover loss of €6 million every hour. These numbers are shocking to say the least, all caused by what is referred to as “[Italian sounding](http://www.sfoodle.com/what-is-the-italian-sounding-phenomenon/)”.
> - Italian sounding phenomenon refers to creating images, colors and names of products very similar to their Italian equivalent. This is despite the fact that these imitations have no connection to the Italian originals they have been made to look and sound like. They don’t have the same “Made in Italy” excellence and they have no link to Italy’s traditions and culture, yet they are raking in millions every hour using the Made in Italy imitation.

- Probably the most famous instance of an "Italian sounding" product is the [Parmesan cheese](http://cheese.about.com/od/cheesebasics/f/parm_parmigiano.htm) whose pronunciation reminds the original *Parmigiano.*

Question:

Is 'Italian sounding', with the above connotation, an expression used in English speaking countries or is it just another English expression invented by some xenophilous Italian bureaucrat?

If not, what is this phenomenon usually referred to in the U.S or in the U.K. For instance?

N.B. This is not a question about marketing, but on the use of an English expression.

Comment: Isn't 'Parmesan' a [protected designation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_indications_and_traditional_specialities_in_the_European_Union#Protected_designation_of_origin_.28PDO.29) label under EU law, like 'Champagne', 'Cognac' and 'Stilton', for instance?

Comment: Yes but, *In the United States, the word "Parmesan" is not regulated. A cheese labeled as Parmesan in the United States might be genuine Parmigiano-Reggiano, but it's more likely to be an imitation.*, but there are thousands of products that just use a 'similar sounding name' as you can see from the links above.

Comment: I do recognise the phenomenon, though: in the UK, there's a brand of pasta sauce with an Italian name, that's heavily marketed with obviously Italian stereotyped comic characters. At the bottom of the screen on the TV adverts is a (very) small logo which says something like "Made in the Netherlands".

Comment: To answer the question being asked: there is no fixed or even regularly-used phrase "Italian-sounding" which connotes a (cheap) imitation or knockoff, no. Also, I imagine your hypothetical beauraucrat is xeno*phobic*, not xeno*philic*, no?

Comment: @Dan - I mean xenophilic ..Italians love using  foreign words, expecially English ones! So when you buy Parmesan in your local store you feel at your ease because of the 'Italian sounding' name.

Comment: Recent issue??  This has been going on for decades, if not centuries.

Comment: @Hot licks, really ? Please show me!!

Comment: @Josh61 - "China"

Comment: @Josh61 Ah, I thought you were imagining an Italian beauraucrat irate because of the false appropriation of Italian culture and brands by foreign interests.

Comment: To answer whether "Italian sounding" is a phrase merely borrowed by Italians, you need to know whether the expression "German sounding" and "British sounding" etc. exist, which they do, (see chasley's answer) but also, whether or not the connotations are *negative*, or if the expression is synonymous  with "fake", "copied", and "imitation". And here, I am at a loss, I think it is an expression which sounds like it's a well-recognized (technical) term/jargon  but in actual fact it isn't. Not yet anyway.

Comment: Note that nothing in the above quoted article implies that "Italian sounding" has become a common idiom, or that it is anything other than the concatenation of "Italian" and "sounding" to achieve the obvious meaning.  The article isn't about the term, it's about the business.

Comment: 'Italian sounding' is not a set phrase in English. It is completely compositional (a phrase that sounds Italian). From the paragraph, 'Made in Italy' sounds like it is the name of a company though.

Comment: @HotLicks - I'm referring to the 'Italian sounding' counterfeit products which is a more recent phenomenon, or at least recently recognised as such.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I probably didn't express myself clearly...unlike other (foreign) products, Italian ones are probably more common , everyday usage, (food, clothing etc.) and Italy is not on the front line, like France or Germany to defend them, so I would like to know if this expression was actually borrowed in the UK or the US where the phenomenon may have already been widely recognised.

Comment: I understood your question, it's clear. But like HotLicks says, the Chinese have been renaming their products and making them sound as if they are French, Italian, Swiss, British, American  etc. for years.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - No, Hot Licks has misunderstood my questions, I am not talking about 'imitations' of the original like the Gucci or Prada bags, but the use of words, that sound like if...without calling the products with the original names. The are many, many products (more then you can imagine)  called, for instance,  like "mozzaralla napolitana" or "Brunillo di Montepulcio"..foreigners would buy them because of the Italian sounding name...it is a more subtle issue.

Comment: And again, this has been going on for a long time.  There's nothing "new" about it.  The only likely change in the way it works would be the Chinese getting into it (to retaliate for us stealing the word "china" to mean glazed ceramic dishes).

Comment: Quasi-Mexican, or pseudo-Mexican, food and clothing are rampant, maybe even more than what you've been noticing with respect to inauthentic Italian imports.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - This has been going on a lot longer than since the Chinese jumped in.  In the US, virtually all cheeses are referred to using their French or Italian names, regardless of where made.  And many US "fashion" brands (even before manufacturing shifted to China) have French or Italian sounding names.  (I'd give examples, but I'm not really into fashion.)

Comment: Italians are experts in the imitation trade too, don't forget :)) Imitation means making a product sound as if it's a world-famous French brand name, a tee-shirt or a perfume. How many fake Lacoste polo shirts have I seen being sold in street markets. It's not a new phenomenon, and it doesn't only affect Italian food products! See: http://www.topdesignmag.com/the-underground-world-of-fake-products-in-30-stunning-images/

Comment: @Mari-LouA        I agree, but that is not the point...I was"just"  asking about the expression...I should have not.

Comment: @Mari-LouA -       It's come up recently, despite Hot Licks comments, that's why I was asking where they took it from. "Made in Italy" has a positive connotation, unlike "Italian sounding".

Comment: [The group estimates the North American market for “Italian-sounding” products is over €24 billion. “No consumer should be misled by a product that evokes Italy when it hasn’t been produced in Italy,” said Luigi Scordamaglia, president of Federalimentare.](http://www.wsj.com/articles/regional-food-names-are-stumbling-block-in-u-s-european-trade-talks-1445298063)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - My suspect is that  the expression is used, expecially in the U.S. , to indicate that sort of counterfeit products, but no user from there seem to recognize it. It might  be a legal usage....or just an Italian usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Answer**

An Italian-sounding product is one whose name suggests it was made in Italy. The words in the name when read, sound like Italian words or names to an English speaker even if they aren't genuine Italian words or names.

**Nuance**

For a native English speaker, there is no judgement implicit in the phrase. The expression "X-sounding" where X is the name of a language is just normal English, e.g.

*"What is the name of your new girlfriend?"*
*"Valentina."*
*"That's a very Spanish-sounding name. Is she Spanish?"*
*"Yes, she's from Madrid."*

The term is completely neutral.

**Generalising**

1. We don't have to specify the nationality, e.g.
   *Did she leave a name?, asked Pereira. It was a foreign-sounding name, replied Celeste, but it's slipped my mind.* [Pereira Declares: A Testimony By Antonio Tabucchi.](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=T2i8fVUIrkQC&pg=PA122&dq=%22foreign%20sounding%20name,%20replied%20Celeste%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22foreign%20sounding%20name%2C%20replied%20Celeste%22&f=false)
2. We don't have to talk about a nationality. Here are some examples with 'name', [Google ngram: a * sounding name](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20*%20sounding%20name&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ca%20%2A%20sounding%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20high%20sounding%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20fine%20sounding%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20better%20sounding%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20pleasant%20sounding%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20good%20sounding%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20similar%20sounding%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20higher%20sounding%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20nice%20sounding%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20foreign%20sounding%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20German%20sounding%20name%3B%2Cc0)
3. In the expression, "X-sounding Y" the X does not have to be a language and the Y doesn't have to be a name. We could talk about 'a raucous-sounding orchestra'.

**Usage in marketing**

In terms of marketing, this refers to a very common phenomenon. For example, in the UK we see many power tools that have 'German-sounding' names. This is because (leaving to one side the Volkswagen debacle) Germany has a reputation for producing high-quality, reliable machinery. The tools themselves might be made in Korea or China.

**Example**

In Britain, it is common knowledge that Bosch tools are made by a German manufacturer. To a Briton, the name Bosch is **very** German-sounding: It is about the most German-sounding name you can imagine (for historical reasons concerning WW 1). Britons also think of German tools as being very reliable.  A Chinese firm might start selling, Gosch tools. Many English people would see this as German-sounding and so be more likely to buy than if they were called, e.g. Wong tools.

**Discussion**

If you are manufacturing food, then your product benefits from having an Italian-sounding name.

If you are manufacturing machinery, then your product benefits from having a German-sounding name.

If you are manufacturing fashion accessories, then your product benefits from having a French-sounding name.

If you are manufacturing electronics, then your product benefits from having a Japanese-sounding name.

There is a whole chapter on the importance of brand names having the right sound in terms of nationality in this book, [Great Brand Name By Jacky Tai](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qRmJAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA116&lpg=PA116&dq=power%20tools%20with%20german%20sounding%20names&source=bl&ots=sBUqoVwbN1&sig=Z_uaqojk1KsTX9xOV0dC4wbdXg8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwA2oVChMIppzX7MviyAIVxtYUCh2AVgEe#v=onepage&q=power%20tools%20with%20german%20sounding%20names&f=false)

Comment: But generally would an 'Italian sounding' product connote a fake product or an original one?

Comment: An Italian sounding product doesn't have to be 'fake'. That would be illegal.  However it is a product that fools people into thinking it is an Italian import whereas it could be made anywhere in the world. As far as I know this isn't prohibited by law and in fact could not be prohibited. I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: Note. There is a whole chapter on the importance of brand names having the right sound in terms of nationality in this  book, https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qRmJAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA116&lpg=PA116&dq=power+tools+with+german+sounding+names&source=bl&ots=sBUqoVwbN1&sig=Z_uaqojk1KsTX9xOV0dC4wbdXg8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwA2oVChMIppzX7MviyAIVxtYUCh2AVgEe#v=onepage&q=power%20tools%20with%20german%20sounding%20names&f=false

Comment: Yes, but mine is not a question about"marketing", I'd like to know is the expression is "commonly" used in English speaking countries  or if it is just one of the many "English" expressions Italian use every day. And if in those countries is has a positive connotation or if it conveys, like in Italy, the idea of a fake product.

Comment: @Josh61 - I've not heard the phrase in this context, no.

Comment: In Britain, the expression "X-sounding" where X is the name of a language is just normal English. It is used in a neutral fashion. Example: A: "What is the name of your new colleague at work?",, B. "Darn it, I can't remember! It's an Italian-sounding name though. I think he's probably from Italy."

Comment: @JHCL, Wouldn't you agree it's a common phrase? If I said, "'Roberto' is a very Spanish-sounding name", that's ordinary idiomatic English.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - Indeed. I meant that it wouldn't be suggestive of some underhanded fakery.

Comment: @Josh61, In the light of your follow-up questions, I have now rewritten the answer.